# JUnit Test framework for Javaagent Instrumentation Framework

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, byte-buddy

What are the standard ways for creating unit tests for code of a Java agent and instrumentation libraries. I have created a Java agent using the Byte Buddy framework for developing a profiler on top of a web applictaion and now i wanted to write JUnit test cases for this agent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take inspiration from [Byte Buddy's own unit tests](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/byte-buddy-dep/src/test/java/net/bytebuddy/agent/builder/AgentBuilderDefaultApplicationTest.java) for creating a Java agent. For this, declare a test dependency on the *byte-buddy-agent* module. That module includes a class that is capable of attaching a Java agent at runtime using `ByteBuddyAgent.install()` which returns an `Instrumentation` instance. Make sure that you remove a Java agent after running a unit test. Otherwise, your agent will remain active for any subsequent test.

On tricky part for creating repeatable tests is the fact that a class must not be loaded before the agent is applied. Byte Buddy's test harness solves this by creating a `ByteArrayClassLoader` that is capable of all the classes that are subject to instrumentation. As this class loader is created dynamically, this can be guaranteed.

Most JDK-bundled VMs are capable of a runtime attachment of a Java agent. To be sure, Byte Buddy does however define a `AgentAttachmentRule` for JUnit that asserts this capability before running a test. You might consider this as well.

Comment: Can you please speficy how to remove the agent in a test? I don't see a #uninstall or similar. Does the "trick" of using a ByteArrayClassLoader also work when loading classes from within the JDK? I am getting a "java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.io".

Comment: Install returns a transformer that can be removed via the instrumentation interface.

Comment: Are bytebuddy's test-jars available in any maven repository to allow us reuse the tools you suggest  like "AgentAttachmentRule" ?

Comment: No they are not, but its 10 lines of code which should be easy enough to recreate. (I do not want to apply such small testing tools with a stable API.)