# ByteBuddy: How to test with classes from java.*

Tags: java, junit, classloader, code-generation, byte-buddy

I'm trying to write a UnitTest for an agent that intercepts calls to classes from java.io (e.g. FileInputStream).

I've followed the hints given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577485/junit-test-framework-for-javaagent-instrumentation-framework) and had a look at ByteBuddys [own](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/byte-buddy-dep/src/test/java/net/bytebuddy/agent/builder/AgentBuilderDefaultApplicationTest.java) UnitTests.

```
private ClassLoader classLoader;

@Before
@AgentAttachmentRule.Enforce
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    classLoader = new ByteArrayClassLoader.ChildFirst(getClass().getClassLoader(),
                                           ClassFileExtraction.of(FileInputStream.class),
                                           DEFAULT_PROTECTION_DOMAIN,
                                           AccessController.getContext(),
                                           ByteArrayClassLoader.PersistenceHandler.MANIFEST,
                                           PackageDefinitionStrategy.NoOp.INSTANCE);
}

@Test
public void testAgentForFileInputStream() throws Exception
{
    MyAgent.premain("");
    Class<?> type = classLoader.loadClass(FileInputStream.class.getName());
    type.getDeclaredMethod("open").invoke("test");
}
```

A similar test for non-java.* classes works fine, however here I receive:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.io

at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:659)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:758)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader.findClass(ByteArrayClassLoader.java:197)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader$ChildFirst.loadClass(ByteArrayClassLoader.java:554)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I've tried setting the SecurityManager to null, without success:

```
System.setSecurityManager(null);
```

If I am not mistaken, intercepting such classes should be possible. This might be due to the use of a custom ClassLoader. However I don't know what needs to be changed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to load any class with the `java.` prefix from any class loader but the bootstrap class loader. This restriction is not enforced by a `SecurityManager` but hard-coded into the `ClassLoader` implementation.

The only way to test these classes is to:

1. Adjust the name during the testing process to allow loading in another class loader.
2. Load the classes into the bootstrap class loader (using the `ByteBuddyAgent` and `ClassInjector.ForInstrumentation`). You should still randomize the names to guarantee test repeatability.

In your case, only option 2 seems feasible. As I do not know what your agent is doing, I can only assume that you try to manipulate the `FileInputStream` class where you would need to use bootstrap loader injection in any case as the a replication of this class would not work with the class's native method adapters.